# In angular2, are there any methods just like $compile()?

Tags: javascript, angular

**In angular2, are there any methods just like $compile() ,like this:**

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
 element.html('<div>Hello {{name}}</div>');
 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}
```

DynamicComponentLoader is being deprecated ...

Comment: It seems this question gets asked every week or so :D